# How do I specify the position of a tikzpicture on a page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, positioning

I have the problem that two consecutive bar charts the edges don't line up.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I.e. is there a way to specify precisely how much space between the left margin of the page and a tikzpicture is used?
[image: bad alignment]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=7.5cm,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
scaled ticks= false,
title style={align=center},
title    = {\textbf{Flowers}},
ybar = 0.9cm,
ymin = 0,
nodes near coords,
xtick=data,
bar width = 1.5cm,
symbolic x coords = {Flowers},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
xmajorticks=false
]
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,123)};
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,32)};
\legend{dandelion, roses}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=7.5cm,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
scaled ticks= false,
title style={align=center},
title    = {\textbf{Even More Flowers}},
ybar = 0.9cm,
ymin = 0,
nodes near coords,
xtick=data,
bar width = 1.5cm,
symbolic x coords = {Flowers},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
xmajorticks=false
]
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,12553)};
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,3442)};
\legend{orchids, lilies}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]` for both your diagrams, or (perhaps better) put both diagrams in the same `tikzpicture`. For that have a look at the `groupplot` library of `pgfplots` (it's described in the manual, and there are many examples here on the site as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i correct understand provided sketch, than you looking for something like this:

[image]

align borders of diagrams is simple with use `\begin{tabular}{r} ... image 1\\ ... image 2 \end{tabular}`. since images have equal size (not considering `ytick` labels, both diagram's left and right borders are aligned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=7.5cm,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
scaled ticks= false,
title style={align=center},
title    = {\textbf{Flowers}},
ybar = 0.9cm,
ymin = 0,
nodes near coords,
xtick=data,
bar width = 1.5cm,
symbolic x coords = {Flowers},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
xmajorticks=false
]
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,123)};
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,32)};
\legend{dandelion, roses}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}     \\
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=7.5cm,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
scaled ticks= false,
title style={align=center},
title    = {\textbf{Even More Flowers}},
ybar = 0.9cm,
ymin = 0,
nodes near coords,
xtick=data,
bar width = 1.5cm,
symbolic x coords = {Flowers},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
xmajorticks=false
]
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,12553)};
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,3442)};
\legend{orchids, lilies}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
considering comment of `pgfplots` package author [dr. Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537/christian-feuers%C3%A4nger) below, the same result can be obtained with use of `trim axis left` option of `tikzpicture` (for details see [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), page 379 -- 380):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left] % <----- 
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=7.5cm,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
scaled ticks= false,
title style={align=center},
title    = {\textbf{Flowers}},
ybar = 0.9cm,
ymin = 0,
nodes near coords,
xtick=data,
bar width = 1.5cm,
symbolic x coords = {Flowers},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
xmajorticks=false,
trim axis left
]
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,123)};
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,32)};
\legend{dandelion, roses}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left] % <----- 
\begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=7.5cm,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
scaled ticks= false,
title style={align=center},
title    = {\textbf{Even More Flowers}},
ybar = 0.9cm,
ymin = 0,
nodes near coords,
xtick=data,
bar width = 1.5cm,
symbolic x coords = {Flowers},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
xmajorticks=false,
]
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,12553)};
\addplot coordinates {(Flowers,3442)};
\legend{orchids, lilies}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer. In case you ever have tick labels or other descriptions beyond your alignment, you can also consider `trim axis right` as outlined in section "Alignment" of the reference manual http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, thank you very much for nice words and pointing me to this option. i learned something new about `pgfplots`! to my answer i add solution with use of  `trim axis left` which works fine.